# Difference between router.pathname and router.route in nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Basically, I want to make of NextJS router to access page url and I do this:

```js
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

const SomeComp = props => {
   const router = useRouter();
}
```

However, `router` has properties `pathname` and `route` that both seem to contain the exact "url" of the page when I `console.log()` them. I've looked at NextJS docs and and I can't see the difference between the two and whether there's some kind of gotcha I should be aware of in using any of the two in accessing the page url

Answer (score 29, accepted):

That is the path of the page in /pages.

Originally there was a difference, but as the version went up, the function of `router.query` are changed and the difference was no longer there.

*In past*

`route`: `String` - Current route

`pathname`: `String` - Current path excluding the query string

---

This explanation disappeared from api documents.

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/commit/18d8c90c3f9bead7ac478f6c9a32bdb5d2591832#diff-129f17bae1a499f319a70b9e5821656cbe48f7b66363d653ab2bfa18e210bdce

Comment: Interesting, they completely removed `route` from the documentation in that commit. Seems like the `route` is just a residue.